# json schema validation fails despite correct type

Tags: json, mongodb, jsonschema

I have a rather large json schema. The problematic part is a smaller schema within the schema called "translations", and which looks like this:

```
"translations": {
    "bsonType": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
        "id": {
            "bsonType": "string"
        },
        "^[a-z]{2}$": {
            "anyOf": [
                {
                    "bsonType": "object"
                },
                {
                    "bsonType": "array"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Where the object defined by the regex contains many more properties (a field called "text", for example) and the array is an array of these objects, but I only left the parts that are important for understanding the structure.

My issue is that when I validate my files against this schema, it fails every single one of them, but when I remove the "bsonType": "object" from the first object in the anyOf array, it works properly.

All of my files are such that at least one of the objects in the translation objects, which have the regular expression as key, are of type "object". so I don't understand why it fails them.

I use mongoDB 3.6.0.

Here is an example for a file that would fail:

```
 "translations":{  
    "id":"12345",
    "br":{  
       "text":"string1"
    },
    "en":{  
       "text":"string2"
    },
    "ja":[  
       {  
          "text":"string3"
       },
       {  
          "text":"string4"
       }
    ],
    "no":[  
       {  
          "text":"string6"
       },
       {  
          "text":"string7"
       }
    ]
 }
```

In case it wasn't clear- the problem is that files like this one fail when the schema is defined with "bsonType": "object" in the first object of the anyOf array, and works when i take that off. The "bsonType": "array" in the second object of the anyOf array works fine.

Comment: Can you provide some of the NodeJS code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem that id collide with the regex try this:

```
let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

let collectionName = 'translations';

let scheme =  {
    $jsonSchema:{
        "bsonType": "object",
        "patternProperties": {
            "^id$":{
                "bsonType":"string"
            },
            "^(?!id)([a-z]{2})$": {
                "anyOf": [
                    {
                        "bsonType": "object"
                    },
                    {
                        "bsonType": "array"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
    }
};

let goodJson ={
    "id": "12345",
    "br":{
        "text":"string1"
    },
    "en":{
        "text":"string2"
    },
    "ja":[
        {
            "text":"string3"
        },
        {
            "text":"string4"
        }
    ],
    "no":[
        {
            "text":"string6"
        },
        {
            "text":"string7"
        }
    ]
};

let badJson ={
    "id": "12345",
    "br":{
        "text":"string1"
    },
    "en":{
        "text":"string2"
    },
    "ja":[
        {
            "text":"string3"
        },
        {
            "text":"string4"
        }
    ],
    "no":[
        {
            "text":"string6"
        },
        {
            "text":"string7"
        }
    ],
    "nt": "not_object_or_array"
};

async function run() {
    let db = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb');
    let dbo = db.db('mydb');
    let collections = await dbo.collections();
    let collectionsNames = collections.map(c => c.s.name);
    if (collectionsNames.includes(collectionName)) {
        console.log('dropping collection');
        await dbo.collection(collectionName).drop();
    }
    console.log('creating collection');
    await dbo.createCollection(collectionName,  {validator: scheme});
    let translationCollection = dbo.collection(collectionName);
    console.log('this will validate successfully');
    await translationCollection.insertOne(goodJson);
    console.log('this will raise validation error because: "nt": "not_object_or_array"');
    try {
        await translationCollection.insertOne(badJson);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    await db.close();
}
run();
```